# Auto video quality twitch

Tags: windows, html, microsoft-edge, twitch

I just noticed with link like http://player.twitch.tv/?channel=hanjarolol&html5 with Microsoft Edge I get auto video quality. Is it possible for me to do the same with Win 7 with some other browser? 
Thanx!

Comment: This is not a programming related question.

Comment: i didn't say it was.

Comment: Stack overflow is only for programming questions. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic